# Error on deploying django + uwsgi + nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to deploy a django project with uWSGI and nginx. I have the next configuration files:

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]

#Django-related settings
chdir = /home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform
module = api.wsgi
#static-map = /static=/home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform/services/static

#Process-related settings
master = true
processes = 10 

# The socket(use the full path to be safe)
socket = /tmp/aml.sock

chmod-socket = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data 

# Clear environment on exit
vacuum = true
```

**uwsgi.service**

```
[Unit]

Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=network.target

[Service]

#User=amlalchy
#Group=www-data

ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown amlalchy:www-data /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform && source /home/amlalchy/anaconda3/bin/activate AmlPlatform && uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/uwsgi.ini'

Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**api.conf** for the nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.prueba.com;
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static {
        root /home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform/services;
    }

    location /media {
        root /home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/aml.sock;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 300s;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error in `/var/log/enginx/error.log` :

```
2020/01/13 10:30:12 [error] 12641#12641: *1 open() "/home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform/services/static/css/global.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: server.prueba.com, request: "GET /static/css/global.css HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/api/login/
```

I am newbie and I don't know what I'm missing because the static files exists... so I would be really grateful for any tip on my error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should run 'collectstatic' to copy the static files to `/home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform/services`

Comment: When you say the static file exists: Where exactly? Do you see it in "/home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform/services/static/css/global.css"?

Answer (score 0):

Where are your static files (css/js/images)? How do you deploy them?
As @ruddra suggested, how do you run your?

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: I did it `./manage.py collectstatic` and it had successfully generated in _/home/amlalchy/api_aml_platform/services/static_ and I can see the files that nginx says 'not found'. Thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: The path in Django in _settings.py_ : `STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'services/static/') #producción`